# Auto deleting files when file count greater than 500 (or XXX) on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I've seen a way to delete files >X days that can be run on a scheduled task:

```
forfiles -p "C:\Test" -s -m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

I was wondering if anyone knows of a command that would delete all files BESIDES the most recent 500?

Or another option would be to delete the oldest files once XXX storage space was hit.

Comment: Can you use PowerShell?  Something like:
`dir -Recurse -Path C:\testfolder | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 500 | %{Remove-Item $_.FullName -WhatIf -Force}`
The "whatif" will let you know what would happen without carrying out the action.

Comment: @HelpingHand: Don't you want to `-Skip 500` (the most recent) and pipe the rest to `Remove-Item`?

Comment: @HelpingHand: Also, `Remove-Item` doesn't need `ForEach`, it can take pipeline input. And when you pipe directly, filenames that would otherwise require `-LiteralPath ` are processed without error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment but, as mentioned powershell can handle this but your system may not have last access time set to update by default. Last write time may not be a useful indicator of whether files are still in use or old but it can also be used.

To query current status

```
fsutil behavior query disablelastaccess
```

To enable

```
fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0
```

Powershell snippet below

```
$Path = ""
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Path $Path | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 500 | Foreach-Object { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force }
```

If your goal is to filter on a date then you can use Get-Date and assign it to a variable and use a comparison operator between LastAccessTime and that variable .

E.g.

```
$Path = ""
$Date = Get-Date
$Date = $Date.AddDays(-90) #Delete 90 Days or Older
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force -Path $Path | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.LastAccessTime -le $Date } | Select-Object -Last 500  | Foreach-Object { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force }
```